# Do I need to finish OAuth flow (exchange code for access token) in Sign in with Apple?

Tags: ios, oauth, sign-in-with-apple

After users sign in, grant permission, and redirect back to my app. I got something like this

```
{"state"=>"xxx",
"code"=>"yyyy", 
"id_token"=>"zzzz",
"user"=>"{
....
}"}
```

Which is everything I need to create a user account, but the OAuth flow isn't finished yet. For a normal flow, we would use that code to fetch access token from `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/generate_and_validate_tokens

My question is, should I do that? It seems to add no value to the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically generate_and_validate_tokens is only if you are using web-based login. If you are using Authenticationservices, then framework handles all the authorisation logic for us. Hence fetching access token from https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token is not required.

Comment: For the web-based logic, I also got the same response without going to https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token. Why do I need to fetching access token with web-based?

Answer (score 0):

Apple is returning **id_token** directly after user authorization in the call-back response if you request for it, which seems to be your case as well. If you just need users identity to create an account or sign in the user to an associated account on your side, you do not need to fetch access/refresh token by exchange code against the /token api. Just make sure to validate the **id_token**  as mentioned in [Verify the Identity token](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/verifying_a_user#3383769) before getting the user details from it.

Exchange of authorization code for access/refresh/ID token will be necessary if you do not request **id_token** in the initial authorization request and you need users identity to proceed. You can then fetch it as per [Retrieve the User’s Information from Apple ID Servers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple#3383773)